# Cox-model with exploratory variable measured after event

Tags: survival, cox-model

I'm interested in applying the Cox proportional hazards model. However, the exploratory variable is measured right after the event (or the censoring) occurs. Does that invalidates the assumptions of the Cox model?

I understand that if the exploratory variable is determined at the start of an experiment (ex: Sex, treatment), the Cox model can be used.

Comment: Do you know the exact time of the event?

Comment: @JoseVictorZambrana time of event for the **uncensored** samples and censoring time for the **censored** samples are exactly known.

Comment: Once the person has the event, he's dropped from the analysis using a regular cox regression. You could have in your model those variables that are not time-dependent, like sex, or any other baseline characteristic. For variables that are dependent on time, I would not include them in the model. Unless you do right censoring and pretend you do not know the event times. The thing of concern in your study design is reverse causation. A right-censoring approach can do what you ask without violating assumptions on the model.

Comment: Consistent with @JoseVictorZambrana the interpretation of the effect of a non-baseline variable is extremely difficult.  It is OK to do a purely discriptive analysis that works backwards, e.g., [this example](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/lrcase1.html) where I modeled the cause of death given patient characteristics and timing of death, and given that the patient died.

Comment: @JoseVictorZambrana Thank you. If all samples are right-censored, how can the model be fit?

Comment: @Codingelephant In R, first create the Surv object (with the appropriate data structure) then use coxph(). Person time will be counted from 0 until you collect covariate data ignoring the outcome date (if any). Actually, you have to create a left truncated or left censored dataset. My bad. Check this representation: https://miro.medium.com/max/720/1*r1Dy1ERX_LKHIX6_nnhXkw.webp

Comment: @JoseVictorZambrana apologizes for the late response. In my understanding the outer summation in the log partial-likelihood function [(link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model#The_Cox_model) is defined over the fully observed samples. Therefore, it's not clear what will happen if all samples are censored.